# jquery extract values from XML

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

How can I show all price/qty combinations from this SQL string returned from a jQuery Ajax call?

```
    <transactions> 
      <transaction> 
          <price>999.99</price>
          <qty>999</qty>
       <transaction>
    </transactions>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myURL',
        dataType: 'xml',
         type:'POST',       
         data:  'data=' + someData, 
         success: function(xml){

    $(xml).find('transactions').each(function() {
         alert(something);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$price = $xml.find( "price" ),
$qty= $xml.find( "qty" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) before traversing it. Try this

```
$.parseXML(xml).find('transactions').each(function() {
     alert($(this).find('price'));//Alerts price
     alert($(this).find('qty'));//Alerts qty
});
```

Answer (score 0):

always parse the `xml` e.g. in jquery you can use `parseXML` using the DOM traversal methods is browser dependent

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$price = $xml.find("price").text();
console.log($price );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/KhNCV/15/